# how to use http-server to expose site to public

Tags: http, server, web-hosting, httpserver

I've set up a local site using http-server.  I can access the site locally on my computer as: http://localhost:8080/myreport.html

Now I need to allow others to access the site on my machine.  I provided the address to a coworker with my ip as http://192.168.56.2:8080/myreport.html but he was not able to access the site.

I checked the http-server site but was not able to find info on how to make a hosted site publicly accessible.  Any idea what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

1/ **localhost** is the local domain of your computer. If you convert it, you will find **127.0.0.1**.

2/ **192.168.56.2** is your private ip address. I invite you to read the wikipedia of the [Private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) definition.

3/ To allow access to your website, you need to know your ***public*** ip address and you need to **OPEN** the **80** port of your ISP.

3bis/ If your coworker is connect at your private network but he can't connect to you website with the private ip address, look if your firewall doesn't block the connections.

> PS: Your question would be more relevant in the **[Super User](https://superuser.com/)** community

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://joaquinlp.me/blog/access-localhost-even-if-ip-changes/) Looks like you must have a dynamic IP, so you can't access it.